# How to dismiss a popover and press something else automatically?

Tags: swift, modal-dialog, mkmapview, popover, master-detail

I am using a Master-Detail layout using a SplitViewController. The detail view is filled with an MKMapView, and each time a cell is pressed in the master view, a popover appears over a corresponding annotation point on the map.

The problem is, if I press cell 1, then in order to press cell 2 and see its popover on the map, I need to somehow dismiss the first popover, because the popovers "freeze" the rest of the UI, i.e. nothing is interact-able without first dismissing the popover.

What I would love to do is to remove this "freezing" functionality from the popover, i.e. anytime anything else outside the popover is tapped, the popover should dismiss and whatever else was tapped should be activated (a button, a cell, a different annotation, doesn't matter)

I have a partial solution, which looks like this:

```
override public func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {

 if pvc != nil{
    pvc?.dismissPopoverAnimated(false)
 }
 pvc = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: cvc)
 pvc!.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(width,height)
 pvc!.presentPopoverFromRect(view.frame, inView: view.superview!, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
 pvc!.passthroughViews = [self.view]
```

What the above does is this: allow the map (self.view) to be interact-able despite the the popover being presented, and now when another annotation is tapped, since `pvc != nil`, it will first dismiss the existing one and then present the new one.

However, since the master and detail classes are separate, I have no way to do something similar for tapping on cells since.

Is there a way to add the cells in the master view to the passthroughViews array, and some way to tell the cell which annotation was tapped beforehand and then dismiss that popover?

I'd appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance